# Unable to save the Lead record since Company is a standard required field in salesforce before insert trigger

Tags: apex, before-trigger

I am trying to copy the value of user selected Status value into the standard salesforce required Company field. Now, when I try to save the record on the object since I am not entering any value in the Company field, the record is not being saved. How do I solve this kind of issue? Any leads appreciated

```
trigger CopyStatusToTitle on Lead (before insert, after insert) {

    List<Lead> leadList = new List<Lead>();
    if(Trigger.isInsert){
        if(Trigger.isBefore){
            //process before insert
              for(Lead l : trigger.New){
                l.Company = l.Status;

            }

        }else if(Trigger.isAfter){
            //process after insert

        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: You can create Lead record without Company value. If its marked as required on Page Layout, then that's only at the UI level. If you have Validation Rules, then you will need to ensure that you have value populated in that field. Not having value from Trigger will always work fine if you are not creating it from UI (and if its marked as required) or if you don't have a Validation Rule. What error do you see if you don't provide one? From where are you creating the Lead - UI/API?

Comment: I don't have any validation rule, it looks like I cannot remove required on that field , so I guess salesforce is throwing standard error like "These required fields must be completed : company".  I want my trigger to save the value the user selects in the status field as the value in the company field and then get saved from the UI that is when a user creates a new Lead record.

Comment: That means the field is required on UI. You can though remove that from the page layout. As long as you have value in the company field, you can go ahead and save it from UI. If you want to change the value to other value, you can do so in trigger. Not sure exactly where are you facing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

When the user is interacting with standard UI, Salesforce validates required fields *prior* to running `before` triggers. From [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm)
:

> 1. Loads the original record from the database or initializes the record for an upsert statement.
> 2. Loads the new record field values from the request and overwrites the old values.
>      If the request came from a standard UI edit page, Salesforce runs system validation to check the record for:
>
>    - Compliance with layout-specific rules
>    - **Required values at the layout level and field-definition level**
>    - Valid field formats
>    - Maximum field length
>
> [...]
>
> 3. Executes all before triggers.

Emphasis mine. Hence, your trigger does not have the opportunity to intervene to populate these fields before the user receives an error.

If you need to allow the user to create a record without populating a standard required field, one route (without writing code) is to use a Quick Action, where you can use [Predefined Field Values](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=predefined_field_values.htm&type=5) to populate these required fields and omit them from the Action Layout:

[image: Lead global action configuration]

Note in the screenshot the use of Predefined Field Values to populate required fields.

Other options include custom URL hack buttons (Classic only, not recommended) and fully customized user interfaces in Visualforce or Lightning that populate require fields prior to executing `insert` DML.